# how to HTML5 APPLICATION-CACHE with asp.net MVC4 for offline web-app?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, web-applications, application-cache

I understand the app cache in html5 with static contents and with normal file extension, 
for example:  index.html,   theme.css, app.js

The question is how to do  app  cache it with MVC4 for web-app?? 
The data is dynamic where comes from api and set-to localStorage.

I want to cache the files *.cshtml (app-template) for using offline.

```
 CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-02-21 v1.0.0

CACHE
/theme.css     *<-- Understand*
/logo.gif
/main.js    
/home/index.cshtml       *<-- is this correct?* 
/sales/dashboard.cshtml    *<--  is this correct?*
/_Answer_below                *<-- please help this

NETWORK:
/config.html

 FALLBACK:
 /html/ /offline.html
```

example.com/home
 route to
 => A).  example.com/home/index.cshtml

or   B).  example.com/home/index.html

or   C).  example.com/home/index

Answer (score 0):

Application cache should specify client URIs, so the one you have on B or C is valid depending on how you set up routing in your mvc app

```
CACHE
/theme.css     *<-- Understand*
/logo.gif
/main.js    
/home/index       
/sales/dashboard
```

cshtml files are server side templatates, which are renered on server, so there is no reason to cache them on the client. Rendered views on the opposite is the one you will cache

Alternative approach is to use some client side mvc framework, like knockout, angular etc, or just some handlebars templates and cache thouse instead of rendered view, together with some data